# Spark Graphframes large dataset and memory Issues

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, graphframes

I want to run a pagerank on relativly large graph 3.5 billion nodes 90 billion edges. And I have been experimenting with different cluster sizes to get it to run. But first the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import graphframes

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

edges_DF = spark.read.parquet('s3://path/to/edges') # 1.4TB total size
verts_DF   = spark.read.parquet('s3://path/to/verts') # 25GB total size

graph_GDF = graphframes.GraphFrame(verts_DF, edges_DF)
graph_GDF = graph_GDF.dropIsolatedVertices()

result_df   = graph_GDF.pageRank(resetProbability=0.15, tol=0.1)
pagerank_df = result_df.vertices
pagerank_df.write.parquet('s3://path/to/output', mode='overwrite')
```

I experienced high garbage collection problems times right from the start. So I experimented with different settings and sizes for the cluster. I mainly followed two articles:

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/05/28/tuning-java-garbage-collection-for-spark-applications.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/

I run the cluster on amazon EMR. These are the relevant setting I currently use:

```
"spark.jars.packages": "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.6,graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11",
"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "false",
"spark.network.timeout":"1600s",
"spark.executor.heartbeatInterval":"120s",
"spark.executor.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'",
"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'",
"spark.storage.level": "MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER",
"spark.rdd.compress": "true",
"spark.shuffle.compress": "true",
"spark.shuffle.spill.compress": "true",
"spark.memory.fraction": "0.80",
"spark.memory.storageFraction": "0.30",
"spark.serializer":"org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer",
"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions":"1216"

"yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled": "false",
"yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled": "false"

"maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"

"fs.s3.maxConnections": "5000",
"fs.s3.consistent": "true",
"fs.s3.consistent.throwExceptionOnInconsistency":"false",
"fs.s3.consistent.retryPolicyType":"fixed",
"fs.s3.consistent.retryPeriodSeconds":"10"
```

I experimented with cluster sizes my first experiment that seemed to work was 
a cluster with the following parameters: `--deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 75 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 36g --driver-memory 36g --driver-cores 5`

With this configuration `GC` time was way down everything was working but since it was a test the cluster it had very "little" memory with `2.7 TB` in total, also after a while I got `ExecutorLostFailure (executor 54 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node Exit status: 137.` Which I thought happened because I left the `node` to little RAM. So I rerun the whole thing but this time with `--executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 35g` and right away my `GC` problems where back and my cluster acted really weird. So I thought I understood the problem that the reason for the high `GC` times was not insufficient memory per executor.

Next cluster I spun up was with the following parameters: `--deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 179 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 45g --driver-memory 45g --driver-cores 5`

So a larger cluster and even more memory per executor as before. everything was running smoothly and I noticed via `ganglia` that the first step took about `5.5 TB` of ram.

I though I understood the issues that using less cores available to my cluster and enlarging the memory of each executor makes the program faster I guessed that it hast to do with the `verts_DF` being about 25gb in size and this way it would fit into the memory of each executor and leave room the calculations (25GB * 179 nearly is 5.5TB).

So the next cluster I spun up had the same number of nodes but I resized the exectuors to: `--num-executors 119 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 75g`

Instantly all the problems where back! High `GC` times the cluster was hanging via `ganglia` I could see the RAM filling up to 8 of 9 available TB. I was baffled. 
I went back and spun up the `--num-executors 179 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 45g` cluster again, which luckily is easy to do with `EMR` because I could just clone it. But now also this configuration did not work. High `GC` times Cluster hitting `8TB` of used memory right away.

What is going on here? It feels like I play roulette sometimes the same config works and other times it does not?

Comment: I know its been a while but I am currently running into a similar issue...Did you ever find a solution/emr cluster configuration that fit your needs?

Comment: I also tried doing this in scala with graphx with similar results. I think the problem lies in the construction of the graph in spark, because I have observed that spark tries to created all possible triplets across the graph. Now the number of all possible triplets in a very large graph that is obviously enormous filling up all the memory. I just implemented my own page rank algorithm that is slower but works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone still stumbles upon this after some time passed it realized that the problem lies with how `graphx` or `graphframes` load the graph. Both try to generate all triplets of the graph they are loading, which with very large graphs resoluts in `OOM` errors, because a graph with 3.5 billion nodes and 70 billion edges has damn many of them. 
I wrote a solution by implementing pagerank in `pyspark`. It is for sure not as fast as a `scala` implementation but it scales and does not run into the described triplet problem. 
I published it on github
https://github.com/thagorx/spark_pagerank

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a stand-alone version, with pyspark and graphframes, you can launch the pyspark `REPL` by executing the following command:

```
pyspark --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 6g --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11
```

Be sure to change the `SPARK_VERSION` environment variable appropriately regarding the latest released version of Spark